# How to auto organize code in Dreamweaver to make it more reader friendly?

Tags: dreamweaver, organizer

I'm using Dreamweaver CS5 as my editor for my code, I disabled a lot of features to make is at basic as possible, because I only need Syntax validation and Dreamweaver code color schemes. I can't find the feature to to auto organize a code, is it possible? if yes could you tell how to achieve it?

For example organizing this code

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="content">
      <p>Content

      </p></div>
  </div>
```

Into this more clean version

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Commands > Clean Up XHTML
```

[*Source*](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7ba0a.html)

Answer (score 0):

Click on **Commands** and then click on **Apply Source Formatting**. DONE!